# How to run 2 threads in the same method without it freezing?

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm creating a game, and I require 2 threads being run in the same method, however, only 1 of them is moving.
The first thread counts in seconds, and the other one handles ingame power
(no, this is not Five Nights at Freddy's).
My game already has quite alot of files, and I do not think showing them all is a good idea, I'll only show the method that starts both threads.

```
@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    System.out.println(e.getX() + ", " + e.getY());
        if (e.getX() > game.panel.startbtnx
            && e.getX() < game.panel.startbtnx + 96
            && e.getY() > game.panel.getHeight() / 2
            && e.getY() < game.panel.getHeight() / 2 + 36) {
        if (game.state == State.MENU) {
            game.state = State.GAME;
            Ingame.alerts.add(new Alert("-9999 Points!"));
            Ingame.powerhandler.start();
            Ingame.secondcounter.start();
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, my "powerhandler" thread works perfectly, however
the "secondcounter" thread does not work, and if I switch they're places,
then only secondcounter works, and not powerhandler.
What should I do?

EDIT: These are my thread codes, I have more threads, but right now I'm only using these 2:

```
class SecondCounterHandler implements Runnable {

    public static int seconds = 0;
    public Thread thread;

    public void start() {
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        while (true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                seconds++;
            } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

and

```
class CityPowerHandler implements Runnable {

    public int power = 100;
    public Thread thread;

    public void start() {
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Thread.yield();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        while (true) {
            if (power > 0) {
                power--;
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                Game.g.state = State.LOSE;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your information posted is not sufficient to make a diagnosis. It sounds as if your background threads are not acting as background threads at all.

Comment: If two threads are not doing the same thing, then they should not be in the same method.  A method should do only one thing.

Comment: @jameslarge But they all have different Thread.sleeps.

Comment: Given that your threads are just looping over a single task with a fixed delay between each execution of that task, you should consider using a [`ScheduledExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) instead of managing your own threads.

Comment: ... or just use simple Timers

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood what you meant by "in the same method".  I see you have two _different_ run methods.

Comment: How do you know that one thread is working while the other is not?  What output do you see, and what output do you expect to see?

Comment: @WarrenDew I just know because the game then shows me using some Graphics stuff.
I know the second counter isn't working because it's always at 0.

Comment: You are going to need to show us the other code that accesses the relevant variables, then.  Most of the special problems of multithreaded code occur because of access to shared data in multiple threads.

Comment: @WarrenDew I didn't really get what you mean, I'll just post all my code:
Note: It's quite alot, and there is alot of bad practice stuff there, too.
http://pastebin.com/0X5mWQ0t

Answer (score 1):

> As you can see, my "powerhandler" thread works perfectly

As we can see?  See from what?  You have not shown us any output or described any behavior.

> however the "secondcounter" thread does not work,

What do you mean it "does not work"?  What would it do if it worked?  What *does* it do instead?

> and if I switch [their] places, then only secondcounter works, and not powerhandler.

What does that mean, "switch their places?"  Threads do not have "places."  Are you talking about the order in which you start them?

---

One thing that might be a problem is here:

```
public void run() {
    ...
    while (true) {
        if (power > 0) {
            power--;
            ...
        } else {
            Game.g.state = State.LOSE;
        }
    }
}
```

As soon as `power` reaches zero (approx 10 seconds after the thread is started), this thread is going to loop forever, using 100% CPU, to continually set `Game.g.state = State.LOSE`.

That might not be what you intended.

Comment: Thanks about that, however that did not fix my problem.

Comment: @nestorishimo10: did you take the `Thread.sleep(...)` out of the if block and put it at the beginning of the while(true) loop? Far better though is to use a Swing Timer and not use these background threads.

Comment: Now I did, and now am getting this exception:
`java.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted
 at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
 at org.speedygoverment.CityPowerHandler.run(Ingame.java:88)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)`

Line 88 is exactly where the Thread.sleep is

Answer (score 1):

Using threads for things like this is not a good idea. Use a swing [Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) instead, it will make a lot of things easier and safer.

**Thread safety**

A swing timer runs on the *Event Dispatch Thread*, that means you don't have to synchronize things for thread safety.
If you use threads and, for example, modify the `power` member variable from another thread, things could get weird:

```
if (power > 0) {
    power--;
    ....
```

This thread could be interrupted between `if` and `power--`, and if another thread sets `power` to zero, `power` may be `-1` in the end.
Such errors can be ***very*** difficult to find later, because the will only occur rarely. Typically, when you are *not* debugging, but showing your program to someone else.

**InterruptedException**

no need to deal with `InterruptedException`s with timers.

**Performance**

should be better without creating many threads.

**Simplicity**

Your code could be more readable with timers, you can handle timer events just like the other events.

Comment: Aha, Ok, I gotch'ya.
I'll try that now, I'll report back when I finish it

Comment: Ok, I changed my Power handling class into a timer (not extended):
http://pastebin.com/M5YxiE5H
However it's not working now.

Comment: I would also replace the `CityPowerHandler` thread with a timer, there is still the problem that james large pointed out. If after doing that, there is still a problem, it would be better to ask a new question with the changed code.

Comment: I already changed CityPowerHandler.
"Ok, I changed my **Power handling class** into a timer"

Comment: Yes, sorry, I was confused by the `start` method. What I mean is: Change both threads to timers. Btw there is a `restart` method for the timer.

Answer (score 0):

At the start of the method run, why not try to add `Thread.yield();` ?

See: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/thread_yield.htm

In that case, the Thread will let other 'waiting' Thread to execute before continuing.

Edit: Try to add the `Thread.yield();` inside the while(true) loop

Comment: I tried that, but secondcounter still isn't working, I'll update my Q with both the thread codes.

Comment: You should not expect a `Thread.yield()` call to do anything at all.  The only place you should ever use it is in a busy-wait loop where, _on some architectures_, it may improve the performance of whatever other thread the waiter is waiting for.

Comment: But if it is put in the while(true) loop, then at each turn the loop will pause and give control to another thread.

Comment: I placed it inside, and secondcounter is still not running.

Comment: @JFPicard That's what `Thread.yield()` is _for_.  The only thing it does, if it does anything at all, is _yield_ the CPU to some other runnable thread.  Here's what makes absolutely no sense whatever:  A call to `Thread.yield()` that is immediately followed by a call to `Thread.sleep()`.   Another way of describing what `Thread.yield()` does is, if it does anything at all, it does exactly the same as what `Thread.sleep(0)` does.

Answer (score 0):

I assumed you using this value somehow on gui (from EDT thread) and noticed it is not changing. If that is the issue, you have visibility problem in your code, accessing variable across different thread without proper publishing/synchronization.

```
public static int seconds = 0;
```

Please use AtomicInteger from java.util.concurrent.atomic package.

```
public static AtomicInteger seconds = new AtomicInteger(0);
```

and use

```
seconds.incrementAndGet();
```

instead of

```
seconds++;
```